# Is there a way to restore my conda command?

Tags: python, terminal, directory, conda, anaconda3

I've been using anaconda for a while now and using the conda command relatively frequently. Recently I had to try installing miniconda for a new project. I ended up trying to delete the directory and reinstall it a new way following the tutorial from my school. I believe I used `rm -rf /Users/MyUsername/software/pkg/miniconda3` . Now, anything I try to use the conda command for returns `zsh: command not found: conda`. Trying to open jupyter notebook returns `zsh: command not found: jupyter` Anaconda still exists on my computer inside /Users/MyUsername/opt/anaconda3 and conda terminal exists inside /Users/emilybaur/opt/anaconda3/condabin which I believe is the default location, so I'm confused why my terminal can't access it.

Anaconda Navigator still works and can open jupyter notebook, but nothing works through terminal. Could I have messed up the path being accessed by terminal somehow, or deleted a part of conda?
(Edited)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you are probably on a Mac? When you installed Anaconda &/or Miniconda, the installer may have added stuff to your `~/.zshrc` (or maybe `~/.zshenv` or `~/.bash_profile` if you're using an older Mac OS). Have a look at that file and — after *backing it up* — try editing the path to match the location of `conda` inside wherever Anaconda 3 is installed (probably your home directory, or find it with `which jupyter`).

Or, if in doubt, edit your question to show the relevant bit of that file, and the output of `which jupyter`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you might not need to replace Anaconda with Miniconda in the first place, you should still be able to achieve the same things.